# Having trouble finding the path of a projectile with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics

I have a system of differential equations that models throwing a projectile with air resistance. I want to find the value of $a$ that will maximize the distance of the throw.

I don't know why, but I can't seem to use trig functions in my set of equations. I've already done this using `DSolve`, but my goal now is to achieve this with `NDSolve`.

```
eq = 
  {y''[t] == -9.81 + 10^-4/0.01*y'[t]*Abs[y'[t]],
   x''[t] == 10^-4/0.01*x'[t]*Abs[x'[t]],
   y'[0] == 20*Sin[a],
   y[0] == 0,
   x[0] == 0,
   x'[0] == 20*Cos[a]}
z = NDSolve[eq, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I am getting the error "Not a number or a rectangular array of numbers"

Edit: I fixed the problem with the error.

```
z = ParametricNDSolve[rownania, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[x[a][t] /. z], Evaluate[y[a][t] /. z]}, {t, 
   0, 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}], {{a, 1.57, "kąt"}, 0, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I can now see graphically for which $a$ the range will be max, but i don't know how to get it numerically

Comment: Try `ParametericNDSolve`, with `a` as a parameter.

Comment: I'd like to add _why_ it does not work. `NDSolve` cannot deal with symbolic parameters. All expressions in `NDSolve` have to evaluate to floating point numbers after substitution of the time variable by a floating point number. But `a` remains symbolic.